# Sourcetree does not respect gitconfig templatedir

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, git-clone, git-config

I have an issue with Sourcetree (3.4.12 on Windows) not copying the content of my templatedir during a repo clone (Git 2.39.1).

I have:

1. a global .gitconfig file located here: C:\Users\my-account\.gitconfig
2. the entry for the template directory in the global .gitconfig is:

```
[init]
    templatedir = C:\\Users\\my-account\\.git_template\\
```

3. a .git-template folder with a hooks folder and a file in it

[image: content of git_template hooks folder]

4. the templatedir is known in the git config

[image: git config knows about tempatedir]

My problem:

When I do a git clone command within the git bash (can be started from within Sourcetree) it works. All files are copied to the .git/hooks folder.

```
git clone https://bitbucket.company/path/testme.git
```

[image: hooks folder contains my files]

When I do a clone via Sourcetree GUI-clone-tab of the same repo, the .git/hooks folder contains only the default items.[image: hooks folder has default files only]

I had a look into Sourcetree Process Log during the clone process. It shows me 3 commands being executed. The first one and its result is listed here:

```
{
    "Command": "git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks config --global --get init.templatedir",
    "Directory": "C:\\Users\\my-account\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\",
    "Status": "Finished",
    "Duration": "00:00:00",
    "CallerContext": "GetGlobalConfig",
    "Output": ""
  }
```

As you can see, there is no output for the command to get the templatedir.

When I use the same command within the git bash (started from within Sourcetree), the result is as I would expect it:
`C:\Users\my-account\.git_template\`

I am lost. I do not see my mistake here. Why is the template content not available in my repo when I do a clone within Sourcetree GUI?
Any ideas are appreciated.
THX in advance :)

Comment: For anyone having the same troubles: It helped me on my Windows 10 machine to add the environment variable called %HOME%. Setting it to the path C:\Users\my-account.